# How to suppress value addresses from debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I can't find solution in Google. I looked at every setting in VS. I couldn't find it. Sorry for possible duplication. But how do I suppress all those addresses in the debugger output? I just want to see the `value_=3` and `"sand.texture"`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why?  Presumably you are using the debugger to because something is going wrong and you need to check what the program is doing.  Seeing/checking where objects have been allocated is part of debugging.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't need that information right now. I just wanna check for example how do boost flyweights working and I am ending up at screenshot number two. I just wanna see `value_=3` and `"sand.texture"`

Comment: Look into [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2022) and [customizing data visualizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2022).

Comment: A .natvis (for c++) xml file lets you define what and how your objects are displayed in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Thanks to @Captain Obvlious I found right answer using format specifiers. Didn't know that Visual Studio have that thing. But here is an answer

1. Add variable to Watch
2. Changed that that variable to this [variableName],na

Here is an example:
[image]
[image]